# What kind of thing does a mongo db.mycollection.aggregate(...) return?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to build an understanding of mongo but many things stay mysterious. I do an aggregate call like this:

```
> db.my_collection_keys.aggregate([ { $project: {value: 1, gaa: {$literal: "baa"}}}])
{ "_id" : "_id", "value" : "dada_id((_id),(_id),(_id),(_id))", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "author", "value" : "(author)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "available", "value" : "(available)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "checkout", "value" : "(checkout)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "language", "value" : "(language)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "pages", "value" : "(pages)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "published_date", "value" : "(published_date)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "publisher_id", "value" : "(publisher_id)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "title", "value" : "(title)", "gaa" : "baa" }
>
```

And what I see looks quite like what I see when I do a .find() on a collection, so I thought this would be a collection, but something like

```
> db.my_collection_keys.aggregate([ { $project: {value: 1, gaa: {$literal: "baa"}}}]).find({$eq: {_id: "author"}})
```

does not work. So what exactly is returned and how can I used it?

(I'm aware of the $out keyword that would write the output into a new collection, but I'm less interested in operation but in understanding.)

---

Edit: thanks to @JohnnyHK I was able to do the following (as a proof of concept):

```
> var myCursor = db.my_collection_keys.aggregate([ { $project: {value: 1, gaa: {$literal: "baa"}}}])
> while (myCursor.hasNext()) {
 x = myCursor.next();
  print(tojson(x));
 db.dudu.insert(x);
}
... ... ... ... {
    "_id" : "_id",
    "value" : "dada_id((_id),(_id),(_id),(_id))",
    "gaa" : "baa"
}
{ "_id" : "author", "value" : "(author)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "available", "value" : "(available)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "checkout", "value" : "(checkout)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "language", "value" : "(language)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "pages", "value" : "(pages)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "published_date", "value" : "(published_date)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "publisher_id", "value" : "(publisher_id)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "title", "value" : "(title)", "gaa" : "baa" }
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.dudu.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : "_id",
    "value" : "dada_id((_id),(_id),(_id),(_id))",
    "gaa" : "baa"
}
{ "_id" : "author", "value" : "(author)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "available", "value" : "(available)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "checkout", "value" : "(checkout)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "language", "value" : "(language)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "pages", "value" : "(pages)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "published_date", "value" : "(published_date)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "publisher_id", "value" : "(publisher_id)", "gaa" : "baa" }
{ "_id" : "title", "value" : "(title)", "gaa" : "baa" }
>
```

to put the documents of the cursor into a collection.
I gather further, *the mongo way to do things* would rather be to add another step in the aggregate pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the shell docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate), `aggregate` returns:

> A [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) to the documents produced by the final stage of the aggregation pipeline operation

The cursor only provides access to the result set, and isn't queryable.

To post-filter the results as you show, you could append a `$match` stage to your pipeline:

```js
db.my_collection_keys.aggregate([ 
    { $project: {value: 1, gaa: {$literal: "baa"}}},
    { $match: {$eq: {_id: "author"}})
]);
```